# c++: constructor dependancy between member classes

Tags: c++, constructor, dependencies

What would be the preferred approach to initializing the following construct?
The problem with the following example is that in order to initialize `renderer_` using it's constructor, I need information from the class `window_`, but the information is only availeable after said class has been initialized, and both instances are initialized concurrently as they are both members of the same class.

```
class GraphicsManager
{
public:
    GraphicsManager(
        const std::string &windowTitle,
        const int &windowWidth,
        const int &windowHeight
        ) : window_(windowTitle,windowWidth,windowHeight),
            renderer_(window_.getHandle()); //IMPOSSIBLE, I presume
private:
    Window window_;
    Renderer renderer_;
};

class Window
{
public:
    Window() : windowHandle_(NULL);
    Window(const std::string &title, const int &width, const int &height);
    ~Window();
    SDL_Window *getHandle();
private:
    SDL_Window *windowHandle_;
};

class Renderer
{
public:
    Renderer() : rendererHandle_(NULL);
    Renderer(SDL_Window *WindowHandle);
    ~Renderer();
private:
    SDL_Renderer *rendererHandle_;
};
```

- Not including `renderer_` in the initialization list of `GraphicsManager`'s constructor at all, thus implicitly calling `renderer_`'s default constructor. In the body of `GraphicsManager`'s constructor I would be assigning a properly initialized `Renderer` class instance to the empty `renderer_`. Is this possible to do in the body of the constructor of `GraphicsManager`?

  ```
  GraphicsManager(
      const std::string &windowTitle,
      const int &windowWidth,
      const int &windowHeight
      ) : window_(windowTitle,windowWidth,windowHeight)
  {
      //doable? is window_ initialized yet at this point?
      renderer_ = Renderer(window_.getHandle());
  }
  ```
- Adding a separate `initialize(parameters)` method to the affected classes, and
  using them to initialize everything instead of relying on the constructor, but thus also delegating the responsiblity of initializing to the client of the classes?
- Changing the composition / hierarchy of the classes to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and both instances are initialized concurrently as they are both members of the same class.

Member variables are initialized in the order in which their declarations appear in the class. Did you try this:

```
GraphicsManager(
    const std::string &windowTitle,
    const int &windowWidth,
    const int &windowHeight
    ) : window_(windowTitle,windowWidth,windowHeight), renderer_(window_.getHandle())
{
}
```

This should work just as well.

Comment: Member variables are initialized in the order in which they appear in class definition. Order in initializer list is irrelevant (although it's safe to keep it same as declaration order).

Comment: Tadeusz, thanks for the correction. Of course you are right, otherwise the order of destruction would have to be affected. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I actually didn't even bother to test if it works "as is" as I was sure it can't be done. I was completely unaware of the importance of declaration order in this regard.